# Сессии соединения с БД в сервлете

Tags: java, oracle, servlet, glassfish

Дано - GlassFish 4.1.0  с такими параметрами соединения с БД Oracle как на при аттаченном файле. [image: screen from glassfish]

Есть код, где я получаю соединение и работаю с ним:

```
@Resource(lookup="jdbc/__somedb")   
private javax.sql.DataSource dsDB;
```

---

```
        Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = dsDB.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

выключаю режим автокоммита
    mConn.setAutoCommit(false);

---

тут я делаю всякие инсерты и апдейты

---

закрываю соединение

```
    try {
        if (conn != null){
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Собственно вопрос, изначально я забыл что у меня выключен автокоммит, и соответственно все мои инсерты и апдейты, при выполнении сервелета, я не мог видеть в БД. Затем когда я поставил в код строчку:

```
            try {
            mConn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

мне помимо текущего инсерта/апдейта прилетели все мои действия сделанные без коммита. В принципе все логично так как сервер приложений держит готовые соединения с БД, и просто подсовывал моему сервелету одно и тоже соединение.

Правильно ли я понимаю что при одновременном обращении при текущих настройках glassfish он мне может дать 8 соединений c БД, а 9 обращению придется ждать пока не освободиться какое то из предыдущих соединений?